# PkgConfig module: INCLUDE_DIRS not listing all directories

Tags: c++, cmake, pkg-config

### Short version (TL;DR)

Using CMake with the PkgConfig module I try to print all the include directories for a library I need for my project, let's call it `thelibrary`. I do this by printing the value of the `THELIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable. The list of include directories is printed, but one directory is missing.

This really surprised it, as if I type the following on a terminal:

```
pkg-config thelibrary --cflags
```

then *all* the include directories are printed, *including* the one missing from `THELIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

The same happens if I try to print the value of `THELIBRARY_CFLAGS`.

How is this possible? Where is the mistake? (Hoping it is a mistake of mine)

### Details

#### Context

I am working on a C++ Cmake project which is compiled correctly under Mac OS but not under Linux (Ubuntu), and when investigating on the possible reasons I found the issue below.

#### Problem

I included the `PkgConfig` module in file `CMakeLists.txt` by writing:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
```

After that, in order to use the library, I set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable by writing:

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/usr/local/opt/thelibrary/pkgconfig:$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}")
```

Finally, I put this instruction to search the library.

```
pkg_check_modules(THELIBRARY thelibrary)
```

Finally, in order to debug, I have tried to print the list of included directories by writing:

```
MESSAGE( STATUS "THELIBRARY DIRS: " ${THELIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

The problem is, **it worked**, in fact it printed a list of include directories, but the problem is that the most important one is missing. In fact, the output is something like:

```
/opt/auxlib1/include/opt/auxlib2/include ...
```

where `auxlib1`, `auxlib2` etc. are auxiliary include directories I need to compile.

But I also expected the dir `/opt/thelibrary/include` in output, which is printed if I use the `pkg-config` command on the terminal as said at the beginning. How is it possible that only that directory is not printed?

Comment: Why don't you try the following `MESSAGE("INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")`

Comment: Thank you @VictorGubin , unfortunately `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` seems empty.

Comment: So print all compiller flags then, i.e. `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`

Comment: The first one is empty, the second one contains `-std=c++11 -Wall`

Comment: Try to remove cache (`CMakeCache.txt` in build directory) and re-run `cmake`. If this won't help, then it seems that CMake processes the first include directory *incorrectly*. If you want us to help in debugging that, we need to see **exact output** of `pkg-config`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think this is a very suggestion, as I have just noticed that `CMakeCache.txt` contains the wrong version of `thelibrary` (an older deleted version), which is also the one which appears when I print `THELIBRARY_VERSION`. When I use `pkg-config` from terminal, the correct version appears instead. I will check everything now.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you @Tsyvarev ! Since your advice (removing `CMakeCache.txt`) solved the problem independently of the used library and it may help other people in general, I suggest you put it as an answer and I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Clean reconfiguration (by removing `CMakeCache.txt`, or by removing whole build directory) is a "universal cure", which could be tried with almost any error. It is like "If you got error, restart PC and try again".

Comment: Ok understood... thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by Tsyvarev (deleting `CMakeCache.txt`), I understood what the cause was, and since this may happen to other people, I hope this explanation helps.

The reason why the directory `/opt/thelibrary/include` wasn't appearing in `THELIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS` is that file **`CMakeCache.txt`** contained information about a **previous version** of the library, whose header files were installed in a directory with a slightly different name, which was *removed* when that previous version was **uninstalled**.

Since that directory does not exist anymore, then it doesn't appear in `THELIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS`, and the new directory does not appear simply because the file `CmakeCache.txt` was still pointing to the previous version.

**Solution:** delete `CmakeCache.txt` and re-run `cmake`.